# Regex - expression contaning two words in site url

Tags: regex

I need regex which will run on site containing both words at the same time.
For example [www.boots.com/**sport**/**nike*](http://www.boots.com/**sport**/**nike*)*
I've found in in other question something like:

```
^(?=.*\bnike\b)(?=.*\bsport\b).*$
```

Would this be correct? First word is a category so it goes between "/" chars, second word is a product name so it might appear between "-" chars.

Comment: You probably want to match `sport` and `nike` in between `/`, right? Then you should use `^(?=.*(?:/|^)nike(?:/|$))(?=.*(?:/|^)sport(?:/|$)).*`

Comment: You should test it, but yes, it looks basically correct.

Comment: Well to be exact: first words is a category so it goes between "/", second word is a product name so it might appear between "-".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\b` is a word boundary and matches in many more contexts than you expect. You need to restrict the context and thus you can use

```
^(?=.*(?:/|^)sport(?:/|$))(?=.*(?:[/-]|^)nike(?:[/-]|$)).*
```

Here,

- `(?=.*(?:/|^)sport(?:/|$))` - the string must contain `sport` at the start or immediately after `/` and at the end of the string or immediately followed with a `/` char
- `(?=.*(?:[/-]|^)nike(?:[/-]|$))` - the string must contain `nike` at the start or immediately after `/` or `-` and at the end of the string or immediately followed with a `/` or `-` chars.

Note you do not need `$` here (that matches the end of string) as `.` matches any chars other than line break chars.

Comment: It works as intended. Thank you very much!